# what is the proper word for 'get around' in German?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I want to say 'when you want to get around in Seoul, it's better to go with your friend', what's the correct or natural word for 'get around'? I've found  umgehn, belaufen, walzen, streunen, stromern but I don't know which one is perfect. It's for getting around for fun or leisure in a town one has never been before.  Is 'unterwegs sein' ok too?

Comment: *unterwegs sein* is the only expression (out of all your examples) that sounds good in my  native german ears.

Comment: In mine as well, that would be an answer I think. Other translations for "get around" (earworm :-)) would be "herumkommen" but doesn't fit so perfectly here, or for news "die Runde machen", "sich herumsprechen".

Comment: Ah thanks. Interesting. Anyone can make it an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unterwegs sein

is the only expression (out of all your examples) that sounds good in my native german ears.

> umgehn, belaufen

are just wrong.

> walzen

may be a regional thing. I never heard of it in the sense that you are talking about.

> streunen, stromern

is what dogs do.

Comment: Ha ha thanks. 'streunen, stromern is what dogs do' I sure will remember the words.

Comment: Interestig. In English, when someone is `on the way`, it sounds like he/she is going somewhere puposedly. Or when something is underway, it is in the process of being done. Compared with `unterwegs sein`.

Comment: @ChanKim: similar sounding or looking expressions in different languages are never really congruent in meaning. Or, just because it sounds or looks similar in two different languages, it doesn't necessarily mean the same.

Comment: DWDS https://www.dwds.de/wb/streunen does not associate "streunen" only to animals. But in fact, "streunende Hunde" is probably the most common occurence. For "stromern" it is similar https://www.dwds.de/wb/stromern.

Answer (score 2):

- *umhergehen/herumgehen* ist sehr unspezifisch und daher oft anwendbar
- *bummeln* wird oft benutzt, wenn man sich Geschäfte anschaut, ohne feste Einkaufsabsicht
- *flanieren, umherstreifen* taugen auch für ungezielteres *spazieren*, auch für Parks geeignet
- *die Stadt anschauen/erkunden* passt, wenn es etwas touristischer ist, mit Sehenswürdigkeiten

Answer (score 1):

Some more suggestions:

> um die Ecken ziehen
> [Example](https://www.fnp.de/lokales/limburg-weilburg/bad-camberg-ort89322/arbeitsloser-rapper-behandelte-freundin-sklavin-10484424.html) : "... durfte auch nicht mehr alleine mit Freunden um die Ecken ziehen."

> herumtreiben (often shortened to *rumtreiben*)

> herumziehen, umherziehen

> (die Gegend) [unsicher machen](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=die+Gegend+unsicher+machen&bool=relevanz&sp0=rart_ou)

Comment: thanks. those expressions seem to give the very close nuance.

Answer (score 0):

'getting around' ist häufig auch in Reiseführern als Überschrift genutzt, um zu beschreiben wie man in einer Stadt von einem Ort zum anderen kommt.

In dem Kontext gibt es keine direkte Übersetzung und keine der in den anderen Postings genannten passt. Die entsprechenden Abschnitte heißen im Deutschen deshalb häufig sowas wie 'Transport' (dies wird bspw. in der deutschen Übersetzung der lonely planet - Reiseführer verwendet), 'Nahverkehr' oder ähnlich.